# I'd like my SVG button to be resized automatically to the same width of the label text (plus a small margin) whenever I change it

Tags: javascript, button, svg, translation, autoresize

On my website I need my buttons to have multilanguage labels. 
I have various SVG buttons with different shapes. The label in each button must be always of the same font size.
The problem is that if I change the label with the various translated versions, the text occupy a different horizontal space for each language.
I need the buttons to be resized to the width of the label when I change the language of the website, according to the width of the translated text.

I don't want to resize the text to a smaller font, because I need to keep the same fonts size. Different labels becomes bigger or smaller depending of the language, and I cannot predict the right size of the buttons to contain exactly the label.

I'd like my SVG button to be resized automatically to the same width of the label text (plus a small margin) whenever I change it.

Is it possible to do a javascript function that does this and embed it as an ECMA script inside all my SVG buttons?

I tried this script but it doesn't work:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?> 
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.0//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-SVG-20010904/DTD/svg10.dtd"> 

<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
 xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
 viewBox="0 0 169 83" preserveAspectRatio="true" width="100%" height="100%"
 onload="init(evt)"> 

  <script type="text/ecmascript">
  <![CDATA[

  function init(evt)
  {
    if ( window.svgDocument == null )
    {
        svgDocument = evt.target.ownerDocument;
    }

    minimum_length = 130;
    my_text = svgDocument.getElementById('ticket_label');
    my_button_rect = svgDocument.getElementById('ticket_internal_rect');

    if(my_text.getComputedTextLength() > minimum_length)
    {
      my_button_rect.setAttributeNS(null, "width", my_text.getComputedTextLength());
    }

}

]]>
   </script>
 ......(svg elements tree)....
 </svg>
```

If not, what could be other solutions?

[image: Fig.1 - How the svg button should resize according to the translated label lenght]

Comment: You might be able to do this in CSS via calc()

Comment: Do you have any example?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc

Comment: Unfortunately it seems to be an experimental feature still lacking universal support. A Javascript solution would be preferred because it will work on every browser.